# customizing dc-tableview via the underlying DataTables object

Tags: datatables, dc.js

dc-tableview is an interactive chart for dc.js library that presents filtered data (by crossfilter.js) in tableview form. The method "getDatatable()" returns underlying DataTable object for advanced manipulation (https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview#object-getdatatable).

Question: how exactly can I use this method (after initialization), in order to be able to (for example):

1. Change the strings (like the "search" label)
2. Format numbers in the columns
3. Perform conditional formatting (like red negative numbers)
4. (work around [this issue](https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview/issues/12)* in tableview by having access to the DataTable object)

Given that:

```
const tableView = new dc.tableview("#tableview-container");
```

- [image: default header of the table], [image: how the header (width) should be]

Comment: When I try to use some of the documented methods - e.g. `enableSearch(true)` - they work. Others -  [`dom("Bftip")`](https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview#void-domstring-content) - do not work ("not a function"). And when I try to use `.getDataTable()` it returns an empty DataTables object. I suspect it would be easier to use the same chart source data, but with a DataTables object directly, instead of using this wrapper library. I am new to this library, so I may be missing something - but the basics do mostly work as advertised. Advanced manipulation: I could not get that to work.

Comment: thanks. I updated the question with "filtered data (by crossfilter.js)", to emphasize the need to use the tableview wrapper library. Using this library means the data in the datatable gets updated based on the filter set by dc.js.

Comment: I am using crossfilter also.